# When i click on tab i lose data and code not looping throw Model again?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

**Hi
i have try to loop throw data in "Categories" Table and it works - i got data when i open View in first time but if i click on a tab to see its content i got only first record ?
i don't know why i lose all data i got in first time ?
Razor Code:**

```
@section personAds{
<h2 class="title text-center">Person Ads</h2>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#propertytab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#carstab" data-toggle="tab">Cars</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">

    @foreach (var personItems in Model.Where(isCompany => isCompany.isCompany == false))
    {
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="propertytab">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfoslide text-center">
                            <img src="@Url.Content(personItems.catImage)" alt="" />
                            <h4>@personItems.catName</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default plus-info"><i class="@personItems.classIcon"></i>More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="carstab">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="single-products">
                        <div class="productinfoslide text-center">
                            <img src="@Url.Content(personItems.catImage)" alt="" />
                            <h4>@personItems.catName</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default plus-info"><i class="@personItems.classIcon"></i>More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

}

**Controller Code:**

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    var model = _db.Categories.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

**and i try to remove where condition and i got same result - when i click on any tab i got only first record ?!**

**Please see the Video of Problem ... [Click Here](https://app.box.com/s/zaxdi74rqrj1tbz84a6b)**

Comment: Any help about this problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your code I think you have simply got your 'foreach' in the wrong position.
It looks like you are creating repeated 'tab' DIV's which will each have just one record in.

This is probably somewhat better, notice I have moved the 'propertytab' outside of the @foreach

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="propertytab"> 
@foreach (var personItems in Model.Where(isCompany => isCompany.isCompany == false))
{

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                    <div class="productinfoslide text-center">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(personItems.catImage)" alt="" />
                        <h4>@personItems.catName</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default plus-info"><i class="@personItems.classIcon"></i>More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
    </div>

 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="carstab">
 @foreach (var personItems in Model.Where(isCompany => isCompany.isCompany == false))
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                    <div class="productinfoslide text-center">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(personItems.catImage)" alt="" />
                        <h4>@personItems.catName</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default plus-info"><i     class="@personItems.classIcon"></i>More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
    </div>
```